# Slider Pure CSS => Text instead of bullets point / Hover on text to change image

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, hover

I'm trying to do a Pure CSS slider but I tried many options (visibility: hidden;, z-index: 11,22,33..) but I didn't find the right way to make it works.

I would like to show a default image (slide-0) until the user mousehover a link below the slider. In this screenshot, no links is hovered so the default image is displayed: https://ibb.co/dX9YBm

**My objective:** 5 links (button-slider) under a default image. When the user mousehover a link, the image change. Each links display it's own image. Here a screenshot with the button-2 hovered: https://ibb.co/bBg8cR => the image (slide-2) is displayed. (it's not working in real...)

When the user unhover the link, the default image must be displayed again.

Here my HTML **for images**:

```
<div class="slider-hp">

<div id="slide-0"><img class="slider-homepage homepage-0" src="http://www.jacquesgiral.com/wp-content/uploads/jacques-giral-photographie-accueil-paris.jpg" alt="Homepage" width="2048" height="688" /></div>

<div id="slide-1"><img class="slider-homepage archi-deco-1" src="http://www.jacquesgiral.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/homepage.jpg" alt="Archi Déco" width="2048" height="614" /></div>

same html structure than "slide-1" for the 4 other images (with other images, and their own ID)
```

Here my HTML **for buttons** below the images of the slider:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
<a  id="button-1" title="Lien vers ARCHI-DÉCO" href="https://www.jacquesgiral.com/portfolio/architecture-decoration/" rel="bookmark">1ST BUTTON</a></div>

<div class="col-md-2">same html than "button-1" structure for the 4 other buttons (with there own ID and title)</div>
```

For the CSS, as I told you, I tried many options but no one work well, so that why I will not share it with you because it's bad.

I would like to do something like:

```
#slide-1, #slide-2, #slide-3, #slide-4, #slide-5{
  visibility: hidden;
}
#button-1 + #slide-1{
      visibility: visible !important;
    }
```

Can you please give me an advice on that?
Bests Regard,

Florian

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: For `foo + bar` to work, the elements `foo` and `bar` must be children of the same parent, and `foo` must come before `bar` in the DOM ...

Comment: @Pete Flexbox & CSS-Grid can help with the layout but you are basically correct. It's possible to have the inputs higher in the DOM but *appear* lower on the page.

Comment: This *could* be done in CSS, but it is much more easily done with Javascript. To save you some headache, if your intention is to use the `:hover` pseudo-selector as an event to trigger a change on a separate element, then that is not how CSS works and is not possible.

Comment: oh god, that !important rule bugs me more than it should

Comment: @Paulie_D I will try to do that!

Comment: @smilebomb You think about onmouseover ?

Comment: @Paulie_D wasn't sure if you could reorder multiple elements together with flex - as it turns out you can - https://jsfiddle.net/rkxqxeo3/

Comment: There is no `onmouseover` in  CSS; that is a javascript event.

Comment: @Pete This project make a lot of sense! I will try to replace the slide by images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pure CSS solution can be easily done with flexbox. Just set the img container as a sibling of the buttons so you can access it with the `~` general sibling combinator, then use `flex-basis:100%` and `flex-wrap:wrap` on the container so it occupies a full row, and negative order so it gets visually above the buttons.

```css
.flex-buttons{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.flex-buttons button{
  flex:1;
  cursor:pointer;
}


.flex-buttons button:nth-child(1):hover ~ .imgs{
  background:red;
}

.flex-buttons button:nth-child(2):hover ~ .imgs{
  background:green;
}

.flex-buttons button:nth-child(3):hover ~ .imgs{
  background:blue;
}

.flex-buttons button:nth-child(4):hover ~ .imgs{
  background:purple;
}

.flex-buttons button:nth-child(5):hover ~ .imgs{
  background:orange;
}

.imgs{
  order:-1;
  flex-basis:100%;
  height:100px;
  border:2px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-buttons">
    <button> Image 1 </button>
    <button> Image 2 </button>
    <button> Image 3 </button>
    <button> Image 4 </button>
    <button> Image 5 </button>
    <div class="imgs"></div>
  </div>
```

Replace the background colors with your imgs and style as needed.

Comment: Thanks so much!! This is exactly my idea!

Comment: @flo-uxdev you're welcome. But please,  when something is "exactly what you want", show appreciation by upvoting and marking the answer as accepted ;)

Comment: I already did but here the msg I get: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly in the console (without the custom css style I'm working on), but on my website 4th and 5th slide aren't displayed... kind of weird!!

```css
   

.flex-buttons{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
 background-image: url('https://www.jacquesgiral.com/wp-content/uploads/jg-photo/0-jacques-giral-photographie-accueil-paris.jpg');
   height:450px;
 
}

.flex-buttons button{
  flex:1;
  cursor:pointer;
 margin-top:2%;
}


.flex-buttons button:nth-child(1):hover ~ .imgs{
  background-image: url('https://www.jacquesgiral.com/wp-content/uploads/jg-photo/1-archi-deco.jpg');
 

}

.flex-buttons button:nth-child(2):hover ~ .imgs{
  background-image: url('https://www.jacquesgiral.com/wp-content/uploads/jg-photo/2-bijoux-montre.jpg');

}

.flex-buttons button:nth-child(3):hover ~ .imgs{
  background-image: url('https://www.jacquesgiral.com/wp-content/uploads/jg-photo/3-cosmetique.jpg');

}

.flex-buttons button:nth-child(4):hover ~ .imgs{
  background-image: url('https://www.jacquesgiral.com/wp-content/uploads/jg-photo/4-edition.jpg');

}

.flex-buttons button:nth-child(5):hover ~ .imgs{
 background-image: url('https://www.jacquesgiral.com/wp-content/uploads/jg-photo/5-people.jpg');
   

}

.imgs{
  order:-1;
 
  flex-basis:100%;
  height:450px;
 background-size:cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;

  
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-buttons">
    <button> <a class="button-slider" title="Lien vers ARCHI-DÉCO" href="#" rel="bookmark">ARCHI-DÉCO</a> </button>
    <button> <a class="button-slider" title="Lien vers BIJOUX-MONTRE" href="#" rel="bookmark">BIJOUX-MONTRE</a> </button>
    <button> <a class="button-slider" title="Lien vers COSMÉTIQUE" href="#" rel="bookmark">COSMÉTIQUE</a> </button>
    <button> <a class="button-slider" title="Lien vers ÉDITION" href="#" rel="bookmark">ÉDITION</a> </button>
    <button> <a class="button-slider" title="Lien vers PEOPLE" href="#" rel="bookmark">PEOPLE</a> </button>
    <div class="imgs"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You can see how it's displayed on my website in this demo version: