# Set animation progress-percent by pure CSS

Tags: html, css, animation

I want something like [the snippet here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48325497/939213) where hovering over one element (**A**) changes another element (**B**). This link shows how to do it. That is not the problem.

However, what I want is to change the progress ("percent") of an animation that is on the targeted element (**B**). E.g. if the user hovers over **A**, I want the progress of **B** to change to 50%.

Is there a way to do that, i.e. to **set the progress of an animation with CSS only**?

If there's no general way but there is some way for `keyframes` that's fine too.

**EDIT**

If I wasn't clear, I want a CSS way to set the following % to 50 when a user hovers over "HERE".

```css
@keyframes k {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}

.a {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  animation: k 10s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<div>HERE</div>
```

Comment: I haven't down-voted, although I have voted to close. I'd hazard a guess that the down-votes would be because you've not shown any code at all (linking to code doesn't count, even if it's hosted here on SO), you've not made, or *shown*, any attempt at solving this problem yourself, you've given only a relatively vague description of the outcome you're trying to achieve (I can't work out whether you want to show `0%`, `1%`...`100%` somewhere or if you want to 'stage' the animations in some way, as shown in [SKorulchuk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50936766/82548) or something else).

Comment: The question is how can I set the progress-percent of a CSS animation by pure CSS. It's all in the title. There is nothing to do here but Google, (which I have. I think that goes without saying.) There is nothing to "try" here. If someone doesn't know what CSS animation is they won't know the answer either.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it's very simple to modify your code sample.

This is my result on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/skorolchuk/pen/oyEBxp)

```css
.flex-buttons{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.flex-buttons button{
  flex:1;
  cursor:pointer;  
}

.progress {
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.7, 1);  
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 0%;
  width: 0%;
  background-color: #3e2a1a4f;
}

.flex-buttons button:nth-child(1):hover ~ .imgs .progress{
  min-width: 20%;
  width: 20%;
}

.flex-buttons button:nth-child(2):hover ~ .imgs .progress{
  min-width: 40%;
  width: 40%;
}

.flex-buttons button:nth-child(3):hover ~ .imgs .progress{
  min-width: 60%;
  width: 60%;
}

.flex-buttons button:nth-child(4):hover ~ .imgs .progress{
  min-width: 80%;
  width: 80%;
}

.flex-buttons button:nth-child(5):hover ~ .imgs .progress{
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.imgs{
  order:-1;
  flex-basis:100%;
  height:100px;
  border:2px solid grey;
  position: repative;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-buttons">
    <button> Image 1 </button>
    <button> Image 2 </button>
    <button> Image 3 </button>
    <button> Image 4 </button>
    <button> Image 5 </button>
    <div class="imgs"><div class="progress"></div></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm referring to CSS `animation`. See for example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation2) .

Comment: I tried to play with css variables, but It creates flickering and doesn't fix animation in `to` state:
`
.flex-buttons button:nth-child(5):hover ~ .imgs .progress{
  --old-width: 80%;
  --width: 100%;
}

@keyframes progress-slide {
  from {
    width: var(--old-width);
    min-width: var(--old-width);
  }
  to {
    width: var(--width);
    min-width: var(--width);
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a specific animation keyframe, but you can rely on the `:hover` state to disable the animation and set the value yourself.  The comments should explain the technique, but it primarily relies on and requires:

1. [CSS Custom Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) for calculation between colors, specifically hue.
2. [Flex Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) to allow the `:hover` event to affect the animation.
3. [hsl()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#hsl()_and_hsla()) because we want to calculate an 80% hue point between the two colors.
4. [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) for doing the calculations.

The example you gave seems vague and likely doesn't capture the practical use case you need, but these techniques can be re-purposed to handle almost any transitory effect.  I would highly recommend that your next SO question include an example you're actually working on.

```css
/* animation from start hue to end */

@keyframes k {
  0% {
    background-color: hsl(var(--hue-start), 100%, 50%);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: hsl(var(--hue-end), 100%, 50%);
  }
}

.a {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  animation: k 10s infinite;
}


/* set css props to use to calculate 80% point */

.progress {
  /* shortest hue turns between red and blue */
  /* 360deg, 240deg would work too */
  --hue-start: 0deg;
  --hue-end: -120deg;
  --hue-diff: calc(var(--hue-end) - var(--hue-start));
}


/* In order to hook onto `HERE`'s `:hover`, we need it structurally before the animation */
.progress {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.trigger {
  order: 2;
}

.a {
  order: 1;
}

.trigger:hover+.a {
  /* hard set background to 80% of the hue difference */
  animation: none;
  background-color: hsl(calc(var(--hue-start) + var(--hue-diff) * .8), 100%, 50%)
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
  <div class="trigger">HERE</div>
  <div class="a"></div>
</div>
```